# Retrieve data from Salesforce using Django

Tags: django, salesforce, rest, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to integrate salesforce *Rest API* with **Django**, so for hours I have been trying to figure out the *endpoint* which it exposes, I have learned to create records but how do I access those records as the URL mentioned in docs is `https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account,`
what is "*yourinstance*" here, any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

when i tried to access above URL in thunder client it gave me this error

```
Couldn't resolve the hostname to an IP address, Verify Url: https://trial65.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have created a Connected App, generated the client id/secret, to get the Bearer Token.

In the response where you get your bearer `token` from Salesforce API [refer this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5) , it also provides you with `instance` URL as part of response.

```json
{"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Dx0000000BV7z/005x00000012Q9P",
"issued_at":"1278448832702",
"instance_url":"https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/",
"signature":"0CmxinZir53Yex7nE0TD+zMpvIWYGb/bdJh6XfOH6EQ=",
"access_token":"00Dx0000000BV7z!AR8AQAxo9UfVkh8AlV0Gomt9Czx9LjHnSSpwBMmbRcgKFmxOtvxjTrKW19ye6PE3Ds1eQz3z8jr3W7_VbWmEu4Q8TVGSTHxs",
"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

Goto `Set Up > MyDomain` There you'll find the My Instance URL for your salesforce org.

[Screen shot of MyDomain page for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnQhH.png)